# Wrong Wallet Balance

Tags: wallet, multibit, balance

I set up *MultiBit Wallet 0.5.13* with three wallets and bought 1BTC to practice with.

- From Wallet 1 I moved .25BTC to Wallet 2,
- then 0.1 BTC from Wallet 2 to Wallet 3.

Wallets 2 and 3 both have correct balances: There are 0.1499BTC in Wallet 2 and 0.1BTC in wallet 3 (the slight difference was caused by the transaction fee).

However, in Wallet 1, which should have about 0.75BTC, the client shows 1.6695BTC.

When I try to move 1.5BTC out of Wallet 1, it says there are not enough BTC to do that... but the "Balance" shows:  1.6695 in the balance box on the top left when I am on Wallet 1.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Would you happen to have the transaction IDs and/or bitcoin addresses in each wallet so we can see what actually happened on the block chain?

Comment: Have you attempted a blockchain reset?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have an address (or addresses) in Wallet 1 to which you do not also have the private key. This would account for both having more money that you should as well as the fact that you can't spend it.